# Is it possible to open different browsers simultaneously fro parallel execution in Selenium Webdriver?

Tags: selenium-webdriver

In my scenario, i have to test my test scripts in both IE and Chrome. Is there any possible way to run the testscripts on both IE and Chrome simultaneously?

Comment: You just run the scenario twice, once with each browser. They will run concurrently. I do it all the time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes - [selenium grid](https://github.com/SeleniumHQ/selenium/wiki/Grid2) this is solution.
The grid allows the distribution tests working in the different environments.